# CUPS-PDF how to tell who printed? (remote instance)

Tags: printing, pdf

I have a cups-pdf setup on a Ubuntu EC2 instance. It works my question is how I can tell what computer printed to it... even if it's by IP address.

What part of the cups-pdf "runtime" would I look to modify.

Offhand I know you can set regarding the filename output constants like `{$user}` or something like (interpolated string/literal?)

I doubt you could pull from the config a remote-ip variable.

I have to associate who printed what, maybe I have to set a virtual printer per computer to be sure who made what.

**Update**

Only other thought I have is to have each user have a printer which can be programmatic but still sucks

Comment: Isn't that in `/var/log/cups/access.log`?

Comment: So it's not built in, I would just read that. I guess that works, I'll respond back with how it goes. Guess depends how many requests/hopefully each ip is mapped with the filename printed.

Comment: This is a crappy solution, but I guess this is our own fault for choosing this solution. Just looking at the logs there's hardly anything there oh well. I'll make it work somehow. The filename is there.